# Photoshop CC: Missing Fonts on Startup, only a few fonts are displayed as replacement options

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I have a Photoshop document which uses some Fonts that I don't have on my Windows PC. When I open the document, I get a Dialog Box called "Missing Fonts", which states:

"Some fonts used in this document are missing. You can sync matching fonts from Typekit, or replace missing fonts with a default or different font used in this document"

This text suggests that I can only replace missing fonts with other fonts already being used in this document. However, I want to replace a missing font with a font that is not yet used in this document. Why can I only replace a missing font with another font already used in the document? For example, I want to replace "Helvetica Neue" with "Liberation Sans", however Liberation Sans is not offered in the Dropdown box, even though it is installed, as it is not yet used in the document. What is the point of only allowing to replace a missing font with a font that is already used in the document, and not with any font installed on the system??

Thanks,

best regards,

Chris

Comment: Hello Chris, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question! This sounds most like a product support question, and you'd be way better off asking about those in the [Adobe Photoshop forums](https://forums.adobe.com/community/photoshop). Because of this, this question might be put on hold soon. Please, don't be discouraged, we are aware that using this site can be a learning curve, but we *are* happy to have you. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Hi, as long as there is an explanation and I can understand it, I don't mind, I've had questions moved or closed on Stackoverflow with no explanation, so I thank you for yours in this case! Thanks :)